# Django ckeditor pastes html tags in wysiwyg

Tags: django, django-admin, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

When I create a post in django admin with ckeditor it makes a goodlooking post. But when I need to edit it, I see all the html tags and styles(all the source) in wysiwyg mode.

When I'm writing:
[image]

After 'save and continue editing'
[image]

I use RichTextField in my model.
P.S. django-ckeditor-updated from PyPI
Maybe something's wrong with my configs?

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'UltraFull',
        'height': 300,
        'toolbar_UltraFull': [
            ['Font', 'FontSize', 'Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
            [
                'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-',
                'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                'Blockquote', '-',
                'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'
            ],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Maximize', 'Source'],
        ],
        'language': 'ru',
        'forcePasteAsPlainText': True,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be 'forcePasteAsPlainText': True,

Clone my repo of the django-ckeditor-extended and run the demo app - https://github.com/riklaunim/django-ckeditor - check if it works for you in the admin, and if so apply your settings and compare

Comment: it works great with your app, but not with mine... it seems problem is on my side

Comment: Do you get any errors in JS console of your browser? If not start adding your configuration piece by piece to the demo until it will replicate the problem.